# Bootstrap 4 mobile menu not working for Wordpress Development

Tags: theme-development, navigation, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I have a custom bootstrap 4 theme I am building out in wordpress. The drop down mobile menu does not work when the hamburger menu is pressed at smaller viewports. I am not sure if I need to add a something to the function.php file for mobile menu, or some other php/wp code for the collapsible nav?

The mobile menu will work when I uncomment the "collapse navbar-collapse" section, but then two menus appear. This tells me all the scripts and css are working. However, I not sure what I am missing I can't seem to figure out what I am missing. I am not using the navwalker script. I would greatly appreciate anyone's help!

HTML Code

```
<header>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">

    <img class="ml-2 NVAlogo" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/NVAlogo.png" alt="logo"><a class="navbar-brand" href="front.html">Nuvision Alliance</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

 <?php

     wp_nav_menu( array(

        'menu'    =>      'primary',

        'container'         =>      'nav',

        'container_class'   =>      'navbar-collapse collapse',

        'menu_class'        =>      'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'

     ));

  ?>



  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
   <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

       <!-- <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="mission.html">Mission</a>
        </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="causes.html">Causes</a>
        </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Blog</a>
        </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>

      </ul>-->

    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an ID in your wp_nav_menu call.  Add `'container_id' =>  'navbarCollapse',` to the array you're passing in. And remove the HTML below it that has all the commented out code in it.

Comment: That worked! thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - ensure jquery.js is present and the link works in the page.